# Onmouseover add border in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, border, onmouseover

I want to add a top border to my navbar buttons when the mouse is hovered over them and then back to its original state when mouse is off the elements.

However my code does not seem to be working, I am using a function to do this in JavaScript as follows:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function border(element){
element.style.borderTop ='3px solid'; 
element.style.borderColor = '#d22b2b';
}
</script>
```

and the HTML:

```
<ul align="center">
<li onmouseover="border(this)"><a href="">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="">About</a></li>
<li><a href="">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

With the above code nothing is happening at all when I hover the mouse over the first `li` element.

Comment: This can be done with pure css, such as: `li:hover { border-top: 3px solid #d22b2b; }`

Comment: @Phylogenesis I tried that, doesn't do anything

Comment: That's the way everyone does it. Show us what you tried.

Comment: `#navbar li a:hover { 
        color: #F56; 
  border-top: 3px solid;
  border-color:#d22b2b;
        } ` This is my CSS that I tried

Comment: In which case, I suspect the function isn't defined by the time you reference it.

Comment: @Phylogenesis It is defined as you see it, I don't quite understand what you mean by that

Comment: This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aGHU2/) shows your code as you specify above. There's nothing wrong with it, so it must be something else. Have you tried the developer tools to debug this issue?

Comment: that code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/NickWilde/Ghdce/

Comment: missed your post @Phylogenesis

Comment: I have the exact same code but its not doing anything

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Shabaz001/A2gkU/ Heres a jsFiddle of how mine looks on my website

Comment: The `overflow: hidden;` style is blocking the border.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code and managed to get it working. Here is the jfiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/A2gkU/2/

The problem was that you had too much padding above/below the links, so even if there was a border showing up above, it got hidden by the padding.

HTML Codes:

```
<div id="navbar">
<ul align="center">
<li><a href="">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="">About</a></li>
<li><a href="">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS codes:

```
#navbar{
background-color: #fff;
overflow:hidden;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
padding:5px;

}

#navbar ul {list-style:none; 
        text-align: center;
        margin: 5px;
        font-family: Segoe UI;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: bold;  
}

#navbar ul li {
display: inline;    
}

#navbar ul li a {
text-decoration:none;
color:#302E2E;
    padding-left: 15px;
background-color: #fff; 

}

#navbar ul li a:hover { color: #F56; border-top: 3px solid #d22b2b;}
```

Comment: Yes you are right, thanks but @Phylogenesis solved it for me already

Comment: yup, i noticed his answer after I posted mine. The overflow basically hid the extra padding :)